# Return the value of one function to another function when both functions are in different python script and directory

Tags: python

Currently, I've two scripts **client.py** and **multi.py**.

In my multi.py I'm calling the deepspeech model through a function **display_output(audio)**. This will call the deepspeech's main() which is in client.py script and display the results at the command prompt.
Instead, I want to get the same result as the output of my display_output(audio) function.

Both the scripts are at a different location.

```
def display_output(audio):

    load_model = "deepspeech --model ./deepspeech-0.6.1-models/output_graph.pbmm --lm ./deepspeech-0.6.1- 
                  models/lm.binary --trie ./deepspeech-0.6.1-models/trie --audio " + audio
    os.system(load_model)
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the output from  main() of client.py to the display_output(audio)
of multi.py. I tried subprocess.check_output, But couldn't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am also using python 3.7.6 on windows 10.

Comment: Save the result to one file, and get it back in another script ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm using that function to handle multiprocessing where I need to get as a return of that  display_output(). While storing the output in a file the order is getting impacted.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason Yang said the easiest way would be to save the result of the first function in a file and then let the second function access it. A cleaner method in my opinion could be: in the second .py file use from first.file.directory import name_of_the_function. By doing this you can access the function from a different .py file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm using that function to handle multiprocessing. To get the output in the order of input I need to return it to the function display_output(audio). I tried to save the result in the .txt file but then it saving the output in the order of processing time.**(not in order of input)**. Below is my multiprocessing code.                                                                                                                              **with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(display_output, audio_with_path)**

Comment: Hello Lorenzo, could you please explain the method of importing the function in detail. I'm not able to get that part.

Comment: >>> import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

>>> form file import function. You need the sys part because python will search there for new file to import. Then you can easily import your function like any other function you would import from a module (for example: from random import randint ). Hope the three command are clear because the comment formatting screw them up...